# Alien Invasion Cartoon Movie

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens, cartoon, alien-invasion

I need help finding the name of a cartoon (movie) which I saw in my childhood.

I only have vague memories of the movie, but the details I remember are:

- It is about an Alien invasion, and this human man falling in love with an alien woman.
- The alien woman is tall, slender and with long white hair.
- She ends up dying to save the Earth, turning into a white flower.
- The movie is from the "VHS-ages" x)

**What is the name of this movie?**

Comment: Do you remember if it was Western animation, anime, or something else?

Comment: it was western animation, definitely not an anime.

Comment: VHS Age I'm guessing means 80's-early 90's?

Comment: @System Yes, thank you :)

Comment: I'm assuming it was in English?

Comment: @System I think it was Serbian dub. This was a loooong time ago o.e

Comment: [Star Blazers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Blazers) ?